# Filtering dashboard by non-predefined date range

Tags: dashboard, filters

Is it possible in Salesforce to select non-predefined date range as a filter on a dashboard? The limitations I found are:

- Max 10 values available for one filter
- Max 3 filters
- Only predefined values

I must say I would be really disappointed if there wouldn't be anything like that as it seems like a pretty common requirement.